# Is there an alternative method or function to 'issorted' in matlab for optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization

have an optimvar maniuplatedVariable that needs to be constrained to be in descending order.

```
sorted = issorted(manipulatedVariable,'descend') == 1;
prob.Constraints.sorted = sorted;
"Error using issorted. Undefined function 'issorted' for input arguments of type 'optim.problemdef.OptimizationVariable'."
```

Is there an alternative function to 'issorted' to implement this constraint?
Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to input an `optminvar`, so you need to create one. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationvariable.optimvar.html

Comment: Note that this may be difficult to handle by a solver. Sorting makes the problem problematic: non-convex, non-differentiable, non-smooth, i.e. really bad. Sometimes this can be modeled with binary variables (possibly making the problem an MINLP).

Comment: Ander - you are correct but A is already an optimvar and the declaration was not shown for brevity. Erwin - in this particular situation the problem is physical (assembly stresses in a spring)  and while i believe a binary model could be implemented, it would be an unreasonable work around due to high dimensionality..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SX!
I had a similar problem, but with variables in *ascending* order. I used a linear inequality constraint, which you can easily adapt, given the optimizer you use accepts linear inequality constraints.

```
lengthOfVar = length(initialValues);
% Inequality Constraint: Second slot after first slot etc.
A = [diag(ones(lengthOfVar,1), 0) - diag(ones(lengthOfVar-1,1), 1), zeros(lengthOfVar)];
A(lengthOfVar, lengthOfVar) = -1;
b = -ones(lengthOfVar, 1);
```

Then, pass `A` and `b` to the optimizer, like this:

```
x = fmincon(objFun, x0, A, b)
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean by pass to the optimizer. Pass them as constraints?

Comment: Yes. For `fmincon`, see the [first example here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-4). Let me update my answer to clarify it. (Please do not use `A` for your _input_ vector, as it is confusing to someone unfamiliar with your code. Rather use `x` or `manipulatedVariable`.)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple but imperfect solution suggested to me on the matlab forum.

`prob.Constraints.sorted = ( A(2:end)<= A(1:end-1)  );`

The issue is the less than or equal to comparator. In the extreme case (that the problem hits) The final array is all equal to each other (which satisfies the constraint). This is ok, but not ideal for my problem.

Comment: At the moment this seems to be the best solution but it may be rotton has a better solution after clarification.